# Show that the continuous ranked probability score is strictly proper

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

I am having trouble verifying a claim from [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1198/016214506000001437?casa_token=Pblz2FZsMv0AAAAA%3A5hBwwUWv3AiORwgYBfMdKpuJCJbRJ7scjQg-pYCDC98uORt7r2Lk89y1Gp9ojTnr15X_ZoVjjPUo&) (section 4.2).

Let $\mathcal P$ be the set of all probability measure on the Borel algebra of $[0,1]$. The continuous ranked probability score for $P \in \mathcal P$ at $x \in [0,1]$ is defined as
$$S(P,x) = \int_0^1 \big(P([0,y]) - \mathbf 1\{y \geq x\}\big)^2dy,$$
where $\mathbf 1\{y \geq x\} = 1$ if $y \geq x$ and $=0$ otherwise.

> **Claim.** For all $P, Q \in \mathcal P$ such that $P \neq Q$
> $$\int S(P,x) P(dx) < \int S(Q,x)P(dx).$$

Can someone prove this or provide a reference?

Comment: Have they not provided a proof of the claim? Also, it seems to me that this is some sort of divergence measure between probability distributions.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I see no proof or reference in the paper.

Comment: There are some brackets off in the definition, kindly correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding and subtracting $Q([0,y])$, one gets
\begin{align}
S(P,x)&=\int_0^1(P([0,y])-1_{[0,y]}(x))^2\, dy=S(Q,x) \\
&\qquad- 2\int_0^1(P([0,y])-Q([0,y]))(1_{[0,y]}(x)-Q([0,y]))\, dy \\
&\qquad+\int_0^1(P([0,y])-Q([0,y]))^2\, dy
\end{align}
Then, taking expectations and interchanging the order of integration,
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 S(P,x)P(dx)&=\int_0^1 S(Q,x)P(dx)-\int_0^1(P([0,y])-Q([0,y]))^2\, dy.
\end{align}

Comment: And how do you know that $\{y: P([0,y] \neq Q([0,y]))\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure when $P \neq Q$?

Comment: In this case, $\int(P([0,y])-Q([0,y]))^2\,dy=0$ iff $P([0,y])=Q([0,y])$ everywhere. If there is $y_0$ s.t. $P([0,y_0])\ne Q([0,y_0])$, then by the right-continuity of $P$ and $Q$, $P([0,y])\ne Q([0,y])$ on an interval $[y_0,y_0+\delta]$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: What about if $P$ and $Q$ are allowed to be merely finitely additive?

Comment: @aduh Do you mean finite measures of finitely-additive?

Comment: What I meant to ask is whether the result still holds if we let $\mathcal P$ be the set of all finitely additive probability measures instead of the set of all countably additive ones.

Comment: That's an interesting question. However, one needs to define the concept of integration in that case, i.e., what is $\int S(P,x)P(dx)$ when $P$ is just finitely additive? Also I relied on the continuity of $P$ and $Q$ which is equivalent to countable additivity.